# Error when creating temporary directory

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to create a temporary directory using the `tempfile.mkdtemp()` method but I'm getting the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/main.py", line 29, in <module>
    tmp = tempfile.mkdtemp()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/V
ersions/2.7/lib/python2.7/tempfile.py", line 331, in mkdtemp
    dir = gettempdir()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/V
ersions/2.7/lib/python2.7/tempfile.py", line 275, in gettempdir
    tempdir = _get_default_tempdir()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/V
ersions/2.7/lib/python2.7/tempfile.py", line 200, in _get_default_tem
pdir
    with _io.open(fd, 'wb', closefd=False) as fp:
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'open'
```

when running this code with Python 2.7.6 and 2.7.11

```
import errno
import shutil
import tempfile

tmp = tempfile.mkdtemp()
try:
    shutil.rmtree(tmp)
except OSError as e:
    if e.errno == errno.ENOENT:
        print "No such file or directory"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have any `io.py` or `io` folder on your PYTHONPATH?

Comment: Works for me. What is the output of `help(_io)`? (run `import _io` first)

Comment: @KlausD. I had created a io.py file that I've now renamed. Updated question with new errors.

Comment: Usually it's one error → one question on SO. If you change the question the comments and answers will not apply anymore.

Comment: @KlausD. You're right, rollbacked and answered

Comment: [The name shadowing trap](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html#the-name-shadowing-trap)

Answer (score 1):

In the directory I had a file named `io.py`, renaming this file resolves the issue which was caused by The Name Shadowing Trap.

[See more here](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html#the-name-shadowing-trap), thanks [J.F. Sebastian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37393369/error-when-creating-temporary-directory/37394093#comment62299056_37393369)

Answer (score -1):

When running the exact script in python 2.7.11 I got no errors. Maybe you can try printing the name of the temporary folder to make sure it is created correctly (before removing it)